# How to force signalR to use POST instead of GET on IE? (To workaround the max RequestUrl length limitation)

Tags: json, internet-explorer, post, signalr, long-polling

I am using SignalR to submit JSON data from client to server.

This works fine on Firefox and Chrome but **fails on IE**.

Digging deeper, i see that though all three are using 'Long-Polling' mechanism for submitting data, IE uses GET request where as the other two use POST. The request fails because my json data is too large to fit within the max length allowed on a GET request url.

Is there a way to force signalR to use POST for IE?
Or is there any other way to handle this?

Let me know if you need more info that might help.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't unless you change the code manually, and in the latest version everything is a GET. What limits are you hitting and what version of SignalR are you using?